# Registering a workflow with a remote Cadence server: Any examples

Tags: uber-cadence

How does one go about registering the workflows with a remote Cadence Server? Almost all examples are pointing to a local server.

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my own question. Wouldn't have solved this without help from Matt Anger.

```
ClientOptions tOptions = ClientOptions.newBuilder().setHost(serverHostName).setPort(serverPort).build() ;
WorkflowServiceTChannel tChannel = new WorkflowServiceTChannel(tOptions);
WorkflowClientOptions clientOptions = WorkflowClientOptions.newBuilder().setDomain(serverDomain).build();
WorkflowClient wfClient = WorkflowClient.newInstance(tChannel,clientOptions);
WorkerFactoryOptions factoryOptions = WorkerFactoryOptions.newBuilder().build();
WorkerFactory factory = WorkerFactory.newInstance(wfClient,factoryOptions);
// the class referred to below is from the tutorial
Worker worker = factory.newWorker("HelloWorldTaskList",
                                            WorkerOptions.newBuilder()
                                            .setMaxConcurrentActivityExecutionSize(100)
                                            .setMaxConcurrentWorkflowExecutionSize(100)
                                            .build());
 worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(HelloWorldImpl.class);
 factory.start();
```